# Crystal reports DLL in PHP

Tags: php, dll, crystal-reports, report

I want to use Crystal Reports DLL files in PHP to be able to generate reports.
The goal is to use crystal reports with a php framework.

I need confirmation that it can work together properly.
If yes, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you want to develop the Crystal logic on your own? Or do you wish to simply use an existing solution via a command line API? Do you need to display an interactive preview of the report or is it good enough to redirect the user to a PDF/Excel/HTML/... export of the report?

Comment: I want to develop the logic, write my own queries and such.
The users can be redirected, it does not have to be interactive.